# Ошибка при парсинге в Python "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page."

Tags: python

Подскажите, пожалуйста, пытаюсь парсить данные по уроку (первый урок):
https://proglib.io/p/parsing-course

Но при выводе появляется ошибка "Please turn JavaScript on and reload the page."
Что с этим делать и как исправить?

[image: Так выглядит результат]

Comment: Видимо, некоторых данных нет в исходном коде страницы, и они формируются/подгружаются с помощью `JavaScript`. Что с этим делать? Можно проанализировать код страницы, узнав как эти данные формируются/подгружаются. А можно использовать `Selenium`.

Comment: Да, там действительно данные подгружаются с других страниц. Но это относится и к первым строкам, непонятно, почему он только в начале способен подгружать, а потом перестаёт и выдает ошибку? Если в отдельном запросе задать обращение к любой из строк, то он всё находит без проблем, а вот в цикле в какой-то момент возникает проблема. Про Selenium почитаю, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Решила проблему, добавив `time.sleep(2)`.
Сказалось на производительности, конечно, но тем не менее.